# Problema Segmentation Fault y errores de memoria C++

Tags: c++, busqueda, vectores

Estoy haciendo una implementación de la búsqueda local. Hasta ahí todo bien, pero cuando llega al return 0 del main (tras mostrar todo correctamente por consola), da Segmentation Fault o diversos fallos de memoria.

He ejecutado gdb y el problema viene al hacer delete de la memoria reservada por un vector. He estado mirando bastante el código y no encuentro donde puede estar el fallo de mi código. El loop principal de la búsqueda local sería el siguiente:

```
do
    {
        
        mejor = false;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < solucion_actual.size(); i++)
        {
            soluciones.push_back(solucion_actual[i]);
        }
        
        seleccionables_anterior = seleccionables;
        
        //Generar todos los vecinos posibles

        while (soluciones.size() > 0)
        {
            seleccionables = seleccionables_anterior;

            Random::shuffle(soluciones);
            pos = soluciones.back();
            soluciones.pop_back();


            while (seleccionables.size() > 0)
            {

                Random::shuffle(seleccionables);

                pos2 = seleccionables.back();
                seleccionables.pop_back(); //Quitamos el nuevo que hemos añadido

                solucion_vecina = genera_vecino(solucion_actual, pos, pos2, n, seleccionables);
                

                vecinos.push_back(solucion_vecina);
                Random::shuffle(vecinos);
               
            }

        }
        double nueva_dispersion;
        seleccionables = seleccionables_anterior;
        int borrar;
        distancias_nuevas = distancias_acumuladas;

        //Aquí se recorren todos los vecinos y si no se encuentra ninguna mejora en todo el entorno salimos del bucle
        while (vecinos.size() > 0 && !mejor)
        {
           
            Random::shuffle(vecinos);

            solucion_vecina = vecinos.back();
            vecinos.pop_back();
            
            indice = indice_cambio(solucion_actual, solucion_vecina);
            nueva_dispersion = fitness_factorizado(solucion_actual, solucion_vecina, distancias_acumuladas, indice, matriz_dist);
            cuenta_ev += 1;
                        

            if (nueva_dispersion < mejor_fitness)
            {

                mejor_fitness = nueva_dispersion;

                seleccionables.push_back(solucion_actual[indice]);
                for (int j = 0; j < seleccionables.size(); j++)
                {
                    if (seleccionables[j] == solucion_vecina[indice])
                    {
                        borrar = j;
                    }
                }

                auto eliminar = seleccionables.begin() + borrar;
                seleccionables.erase(eliminar);
                solucion_actual = solucion_vecina;
                mejor = true;
            }
             
            else
            {
                distancias_acumuladas = distancias_nuevas;
            }
        }

       
        if (mejor == false)
        {
            salir = true;
        }
        
        //Si no tenemos mejora
    }while (!salir && cuenta_ev <= 100000);

    
    
    cout << " M" << mejor_fitness << endl;

    return 0;
```

El mejor fitness llega a imprimirlo y, según gdb, el problema está en el vector distancias_acumuladas, que solo es modificado en el método fitness_factorizado.
Si alguien detectara algún error en el código insertado me sería de gran ayuda y si hicera falta más código de algún método lo aporto lo antes posible.

El código de la función fitness_factorizado es el siguiente:

```
double fitness_factorizado(vector<int> solucion_actual, vector<int> solucion_vecina, vector<double> &distancias_acumuladas, int indice_cambio, vector<vector<double>> &matriz_distancias)
{
    double suma = 0;
    double maximo_nuevo = 0, minimo_nuevo = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < distancias_acumuladas.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != indice_cambio)
            distancias_acumuladas[i] -= matriz_distancias[solucion_actual[indice_cambio]][solucion_actual[i]];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < distancias_acumuladas.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i != indice_cambio)
        {


            distancias_acumuladas[i] += matriz_distancias[solucion_vecina[indice_cambio]][solucion_actual[i]];

            suma += matriz_distancias[solucion_vecina[indice_cambio]][solucion_actual[i]];
        }
    }

    distancias_acumuladas[indice_cambio] = suma;

    for (int i = 0; i < distancias_acumuladas.size(); i++)
    {
        double distancia = distancias_acumuladas[i];
        if (distancia > maximo_nuevo)
        {
            maximo_nuevo = distancia;
        }

        if (minimo_nuevo == 0)
        {
            minimo_nuevo = distancia;
        }

        else
        {
            if (distancia < minimo_nuevo)
            {
                minimo_nuevo = distancia;
            }
        }
    }
    return (maximo_nuevo - minimo_nuevo);
}
```

Dependiendo del conjunto de distancias elegido al principio, el fallo que me sale justo después de imprimir el **mejor_fitness** varía entre Segmentation_fault, free(): invalid size y munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer.

Muchas gracias de antemano.